# how to flip Boolean answer with angular mat-checkbox formControlName

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

if checkbox is checked i need to return false in reactive form controller
this is my html:

```
<mat-checkbox formControlName="EmailOptout" class="form-cb-prom"><mat-checkbox>
```

in ts

```
EmailOptout: [this.EmailOptout]
```

Comment: if you set it up correctly the element should be bound to the variable and always show its state. can you show more of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngModel` if you only need to flip boolean answer,

In .html:

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)] = "EmailOptout" class="form-cb-prom"> 
   <label>Flipped value is {{!EmailOptout}}</label>
<mat-checkbox>
```

In .ts:

```
EmailOptout:boolean;
```